# SearchView for Recyclerview in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, searchview

I'm trying to search through a recyclerview using a searchview inside of a fragment

My Adapter

```
public class AdapterActiveJob extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterActiveJob.ViewHolderActiveJob>  implements Filterable{

public ArrayList<JobsTest> listjobs = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<JobsTest> filterlist;
public ArrayList<JobsTest> filteredjobs = new ArrayList<>();
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Context ctx;
CustomFilter filter;

public AdapterActiveJob(Context context){
    layoutInflater = layoutInflater.from(context);
    //this.listjobs = listjobs;
    //this.filterlist = listjobs;


}

public void setListjobs(ArrayList<JobsTest> listjobs, Context ctx){
    this.listjobs = listjobs;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0,listjobs.size());
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.filterlist = listjobs;

}

//Methods....


//Search attempt 1
        public void filter(String constraint) {

    if (constraint != null && constraint.length()>0){

        //change to lowercase
        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        //Store filtered players here

   // filteredjobs = new ArrayList<JobsTest>();
    for(int i = 0;i<filterlist.size();i++){
        //check
        if(filterlist.get(i).getCustomer().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)){
            //Add job
            filteredjobs.add(filterlist.get(i));
        }

    }}
    notifyDataSetChanged();


}


//Search attempt 2

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    //Filtering logic
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {

                //change to lowercase
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                //Store filtered players here
                ArrayList<JobsTest> filteredlist = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < filterlist.size(); i++) {
                    //check
                    if (filterlist.get(i).getCustomer().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                        //Add job
                        filteredlist.add(filterlist.get(i));
                    }

                }
                results.count = filteredlist.size();
                results.values = filteredlist;

            } else {
                results.count = filterlist.size();
                results.values = filterlist;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {

           listjobs.addAll((ArrayList<JobsTest>)results.values);

            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };


}
}
```

Inside my fragment

```
public class ActiveFragment extends Fragment implements SortListener{

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_active, container, false);
    textVolleyError = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textVolleyError);
    listJobs = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.listJobs);
    listJobs.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    adapterActiveJob = new AdapterActiveJob(getActivity());
    //Add Item Decoration
    listJobs.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity()));
    listJobs.setAdapter(adapterActiveJob);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){

        jobList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_JOBS);
        adapterActiveJob.setListjobs(jobList,getActivity());
    }

    else{sendJsonRequest();}

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
   SearchView sv = new SearchView(((Main2Activity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
   MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
   MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, sv);
   sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
           System.out.println("search query submit");
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
           System.out.println("tap");
           adapterActiveJob.filter(newText.toString());
           return false;
       }
   });
  }
```

Nothing happens when I type in the searchview other than the system printing "tap". Help I'm an idiot.

Comment: Can you check what is 'filterlist.size()' in your first search attempt and see if its 0 or what ?

Comment: I/System.out: filterlist size is: 5 ...Which is correct

Comment: which object you are using inside the adapter to use the data from ? is it **listjobs** ? if yes, then the reason for your search not working is you are adding `jobs` to `filteredJobs` object while `listjobs` is being used inside the adapter so its not updating the view.

Comment: listjobs is where I get the data drom yes.. So I should change the line `filteredjobs.add(filterlist.get(i));` to 'listjobs.add(filterlist.get(i));` ?? @SatyenUdeshi

Comment: Yes doing that should work

Comment: It froze up and then crashed after I entered the first letter`bricco.com.telicon W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.417ms
bricco.com.telicon I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 175092(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 29MB/34MB, paused 5.794ms total 77.966ms` Then the app crashed